# Populating spinner with custom object .how to set spinner hint in custom object

Tags: java, android

I am developing one application where one spinner are there I am parsing JSON in the spinner and setting an adapter with the custom object. now I am getting an issue unable to set hint . as in image first country coming to Afghanistan but it should come like  " Select Country " as a hint. please help me I am stuck in this from 2 days. thanks in advance.

List mCountryList ;

private void getCountry() {
ApiService countryApi = RetrofitClient.getApiService();

```
    Call<JsonElement> call = countryApi.getCountry();    

    mCountryList = new ArrayList<>();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {


            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                try {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response.body().toString());

                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(object.toString());

                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");

                    if (jsonArray.length() > 0) {

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            Country countryList = new Country();

                            countryList.setId(jsonObject.getInt("id"));

                            countryList.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));

                            countryList.setCode(jsonObject.getString("code"));

                            mCountryList.add(countryList);

                        }
                        ArrayAdapter<Country> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Country>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.spinner_layout, mCountryList);
                        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        mSpinnerCountry.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else if (response.code() == 401 || response.code() == 500) {
                Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, "Session Expired", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, "Something Went Wrong..!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, "Something Went Wrong..!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}[enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way is to create a dummy Country object at beginning and add to array whose name is `Select Country` and fill other dummy details which you might be needing and while tapping on any form button (assuming you have one) you can check the current selected index and if it is `0` then no country is selected. In that case you can show a Toast.

For example here is your updated try catch block:

```
try {
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response.body().toString());
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(object.toString());
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");

    if (jsonArray.length() > 0) {

        Country country = new Country();
        country.setId(0);
        country.setName("Select Country");
        country.setCode(0);
        mCountryList.add(country);


        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            Country country = new Country();
            country.setId(jsonObject.getInt("id"));
            country.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
            country.setCode(jsonObject.getString("code"));
            mCountryList.add(country);

        }
        ArrayAdapter < Country > arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter < Country > (getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_layout, country);
        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mSpinnerCountry.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

1st element is your hint and make sure you check the index when you are actually want to take any action i.e. if index is `0` show user a Toast to select a Country.

Comment: Can you write here the dummy code that I can understand easily ?

Comment: Great. Happy coding.

Comment: the hint is coming with spinner items. can we remove from the list should show only as a hint?

Comment: Ok, Thank you so much for this suggestion.